# Bcrypt in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, hash, passwords, bcrypt

I do store my passwords as a bcrypt hash in a MySQL database. With MD5 and SHA1 it was possible to run the hashing function inside the database. Now I wonder if it is possible to run bcrypt inside MySQL. I would like to create user account inside the database.

I could not find it in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html) or did I miss it? Maybe as stored procedure?

Answer (score 4):

As soon as you use a unique salt for each password (and save it together with the password), you won't be able to do the verification in a single SQL statement, especially not with a slow hash function.

In a first step we should make a query to get the hash-value (and the salt) by username, then in a second step we can validate the entered password with this hash-value and the same salt. If you try to do this in a single SQL statement, the database would have to calculate the hash for each row until a match is found, with a slow hash-function like BCrypt this query would overload your server.

Comment: Thanks. I did not mention that I was only thinking about account creation not about login validation.

Comment: @PiTheNumber - Creation alone would actually work, but when i last checked i didn't find any appropriate function in MySql to hash passwords. Actually it would be quite difficult to implement this, because people will expect it to work for verification too, and then the optimiser would have to analyse the SQL and give the hash function the lowest priority (and hope there are other filters like username as well).